# Subsetting a dataset by selecting variables based on keywords in their name in SAS

Tags: sas, subset, variable-names

I hope someone can help. I have a large dataset imported to SAS with thousands of variables. I want to create a new dataset by extracting variables that have a specific keyword in their name. For example, the following variables are in my dataset:

> AAYAN_KK_Equity_Ask
>   AAYAN_KK_Equity_Bid
>   AAYAN_KK_Equity_Close
>   AAYAN_KK_Equity_Date
>   AAYAN_KK_Equity_Volume
>   AAYANRE_KK_Equity_Ask
>   AAYANRE_KK_Equity_Bid
>   AAYANRE_KK_Equity_Close
>   AAYANRE_KK_Equity_Date

I want to extract variables that end with _Ask and _Bid without knowing the rest of the variable's name. Is there a way to do that? I want to try using a do loop but don't know how to instruct SAS to compare each variable's last part of the name with _Ask or _Bid.

Afterwords. I want to create a new variable for each set that starts with full name of the variable except the last part (Which is _Ask or _Bid). Can I do that in using an assignment statement?

Comment: You would end up with variables that have the same name then? That isn't allowed or are your planning to put them in separate data sets?

Comment: The variables with _Bid or _Ask at the end, I want to put them in a separate data set. From these variables later, I want to create a new variable that has the same name for each variable except the ending will be different (the variable will end with _MID instead of _Bid or _Ask)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to query sashelp.vtable which holds the metadata about your data set. Assuming your data is in the library WORK and called TABLE the following creates a list of the variables that end in ASK.

```
proc sql;
select name into :varlist separated by " "
from sashelp.vcolumn
where libname="WORK" and memname="TABLE" and upcase(name) like '%_ASK';
quit;

*To rename the variables with MID generate a rename statement;
proc sql;
    select catx("=", name, tranwrd(upcase(name), "_ASK", "_MID"))
    into :rename_list separated by " "
    from sashelp.vcolumn
    where libname="WORK" and memname="TABLE" and upcase(name) like '%_ASK';
quit;

%put &rename_list;


data want_ask;
set work.table
 (keep = &varlist);
 rename &rename_list;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you Reese for your answer. However, there seems to be a problem as SAS is interpreting "%_ASK" as a macro variable. I get the following message: WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro _ASK not resolved and then the following ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: Clean_prices, Kuwait,
       libname, memname, name.

Comment: For the error message to be meaningful, Kuwait is the libname clean_prices is the dataset.

Comment: I updated the code.  a `like` statement in PROC SQL with the `%` wildcard needs a single quote instead of the double quote that was given.

Comment: I hope I am not driving you guys crazy, but this starts to do so to me. I tried to use the PROC SQL but it didn't work. I am getting the this error `ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: name.` I investigated further to see what is wrong. I ran the following `PROC PRINT` to check what's inside `sashelp.vtable`:`proc print data=Sashelp.Vtable noobs; where libname='Work'; run;` and it is returning 0 observations. Although I am sure that `sashelp.vtable` is available (I opened it), it seems SAS is not reading the file properly. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, should have referred to SASHELP.VCOLUMN. However if your database is on a server, i.e. SQL or Oracle this may not work either. You probably got 0 in your query because it is case sensitive. try libname="WORK" instead.

Comment: Thank you Reese and DomPazz, your help solved my problem. I appreciate it.